# Validation of flow cytometer (Facs Canto II)

Tags: validation

I was just wondering if 3 biological samples would be statiscally significant for both precision testing and calibration verification.

Precision: to check whether instrument is able to give consistent results when a sample is being run repeatedly.

Calibration Verification: to check whether instrument is able to obtain a measured value close to the assigned value (provided by manufacturer).

I am validating a flow cytometer which has been shipped from another laboratory.

Thanks.